# Android Threading (AsyncTasks) acting a little weird

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

From my main thread, I start an AsyncTask which will go through a list of images and for each image, it will do some processing on it. So basically, there's a for loop and inside it, another AsyncTask is called. I use an instance of a class which holds the boolean value for checking if each image is done with its processing, its called a dummyStructure.

Code of the main thread:

```
new BatchProcessor().execute()
```

the doInBackground of the BatchProcessor:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

while(dummyStructure.isWorking())
{
//Try loop
  thread.sleep(1000);
}
  dummyStructure.setIsWorking(true); //basically sets the flag to true
for(String s: pictureList)
{
  RunTheProcessingLoop().execute();
}
```

The Problem:
I tried debugging, and here's what the problem is imo, if I remove the line just outside the while loop `dummyStrucutre.setIsWorking(true)` then there are multiple asyncTasks called even before it finishes, and basically everything gets screwed up. However, if I don't remove that line, then the `BatchProcessor` AsyncTask gets caught in the while loop, while as the `RunTheProcessingLoop` AsyncTask never executes beyond its `onPreExecute()`(debugged to know that, I used `Log.e()` in every method of that asyncTask).

Definitely I'm missing something, any help? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why would you call an async task from another async task?  Async in Android are basically scheduled jobs that work within the main application framework.  This often can save cpu resources by making sure all these kinds of jobs run from the same scheduler mechanism.  When you call execute it adds it to the schedule queue there is no logic to prevent you from adding a job more than once to the scheduler.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But then how do I call the main AsyncTask -> `RunTheProcessingLoop()` from the main thread and also wait for it to finish? I believe I would need to call it several times as per the requirements. :\

Comment: Don't run things from the main thread.  Waiting for the AsyncTask to finish is against the design of AsyncTask in general.  The first rule of AsyncTasks is that all the logic run by AsyncTasks should be accessible from anywhere else directly and not through the AsyncTask limited interface.  This allows you to directly invoke different task blocks from other tasks.  Post as much of the code for that class you can to pastebin and I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are encountering is asynctasks getting piled up because you are starting one from another and not exiting the first. This is because the asynctasks are handled serially by a single thread by default. If you want to use multiple threads in parallel, you'd need to use your own thread executor. See the `AsyncTask` documentation for more details.

Comment: You are super awesome! Thanks a lot @LarrySchiefer, that helped me a lot. I am aware that it might not lie under 'best programming practices in Java/Android', but the good news is, IT WORKS!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

So after 2 days of posting this question and finding out more about what people posted, I figured this:

My main thread called for an AsyncTask and I wanted to wait for that AsyncTask to finish. So I used a boolean flag which the AsyncTask sets to false once it is done and I can queue another task. Here's the code:

```
class mExecutor implements Executor {
           public void execute(Runnable r) {
             new Thread(r).start();

         }}
```

Now, all you need to do is, whatever task/method/etc you want to run Asynchronously, simply create a thread and push it in that class, example:

```
Thread t = new  Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            new someshit().execute();
                                }
                            });
new mExecutor().execute(t);
```

and Tada! Now they both won't be queued/synchronized but would run in parallel.

If I am wrong, please correct me! Thanks! :)